# Hibernate + Spring + MySQL : Changes done in one transaction are not visible in the next transaction sometimes

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

We have a REST based web application running in Tomcat server which uses Hibernate + Spring and connects to MySQL DB running in GCP. Recently we setup a cluster of these servers with a load balancer in the front to support increased load. After this, we have observed that in some cases, changes done in one transaction does not reflect in the next transaction on the same server even if the second transaction starts only after the first transaction is completed.

To elaborate more :
At time t1, there is a call to a REST method on server S1 to recharge the account. This just invokes a method in the service layer. The service layer and DAO layer classes are shown below. From logs I can see that the account balance was X before updating and this changed to Y after updating.
After this REST call completes, there is another call to get the account data. But the logs in this method show old balance X. This REST call reached the same server S1. What is wrong in my code? Why is the change done in the first REST call not visible in the second REST call?

P.S : In case it matters, we use the default transaction isolation level of REPEATABLE_READ in MySQL DB.

```
@Service
public class AccountManager
{
    public Account getAccount(long accountId) throws AccountException 
    {
        return accountDAO.getAccount(accountId);
    }

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED,rollbackFor={Exception.class})
    public double rechargeAccount(long accountId, int amount, String orderId, String source) throws AccountException
    {   
        accountDAO.lockAccount(accountId);
        ...
        ... // some validations

        AccountTransaction rechargeTransaction = new AccountTransaction(...);               
        double newBalance = makeTransactionOnAccount(rechargeTransaction);
        return newBalance;
    }

    private double makeTransactionOnAccount(AccountTransaction accountTransaction) throws AccountException
    {
        ...
        newBalance= depositAmount(accountTransaction);
        accountDAO.createAccountTransaction(accountTransaction);
        return newBalance;
    }

    private double depositAmount(AccountTransaction accountTransaction)  
    {
        double balance = Math.floor((accountTransaction.getValue())* 100) / 100;
        accountDAO.increaseBalance(accountTransaction.getAccountId(), balance); 
        return accountDAO.getBalance(accountTransaction.getAccountId());
    }
}

@Component
public class AccountDAOImpl implements AccountDAO
{
    @Override
    public void lockAccount (long accountId) throws AccountException
    {
        log.debug("Locking account {} for update", accountId);
        // Pessimistic locking
        Session session = sessionFactry.getCurrentSession();
        session.load(Account.class, accountId, LockOptions.UPGRADE);
    }

    @Override
    public void increaseBalance(long accountId, double valueToBeIncreased) throws AccountException
    {
        try
        {
            Session currentSession = sessionFactry.getCurrentSession();
            Account account = getAccount(accountId);
            account.setBalance(account.getBalance() + valueToBeIncreased);
            currentSession.saveOrUpdate(account);
            currentSession.flush();
            String updateAccountBalanceSQL = getUpdateAccountBalanceSQL(accountId, account.getBalance());
            imptTxnLogger.info("{}", updateAccountBalanceSQL);
        }
        catch (HibernateException he)
        {
            log.error("Increasing balance failed",he);
            throw new AccountException(AccountException.ACCOUNT_UPDATE_FAILED, he.getCause());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Account getAccount(long accountid)  
    {
        try
        {
            Account account = (Account)sessionFactry.getCurrentSession().get(Account.class, accountid);
            log.debug("Account = {}", account);
            return account; 
        } 
        catch (HibernateException he)
        {
            log.error("getting  account details failed",he);
            throw new AccountException(AccountException.ACCOUNT_READ_FAILED,he.getCause());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public double getBalance(long accountId) 
    {
        Account account = getAccount(accountId);
        return account.getBalance();
    }
}
```

Comment: How often do you see this behaviour? This behaviour begun just after the clusterization?

Comment: @CarlitosWay : Not always .. I have noticed it about 2 times in a day; there maybe few more occurrences though, but definitely does not happen always. I have never been able to reproduce this in my local cluster with 2 servers. I have noticed this behaviour only after clusterization

Comment: Any sort of hibernate caching enabled? BTW, using `double` type for money is a bad choice, `BigDecimal` is recommended

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko : Yes, secondary cache is enabled in hibernate.cfg.xml with factory class set to "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory". At the entity level, in hbm file, cache is set to read-write : <cache usage="read-write"/>

Comment: Have you checked your database after this behaviour happens... I mean, did the balance record was really updated or not? I'm asking this because may be your are seeing (somehow) a cached value, not the actual value...

Comment: @CarlitosWay : I have checked the database after some time (not immediately after the first transaction) and found old balance. But as I mentioned, this doesn't happen always, only sometimes.